# I would like to understand how to play the Live Stream / VOD on native Android App

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, jwplayer

We want to create a Live-Broadcasting/streaming platform where anyone can go live on click of a button using his/her mobile camera. The same live feed should be viewable from the native mobile App. To start with, we would like to support live broadcast and viewing live feed from both IOS and Android platforms. We are using Wowza as the media streaming server

UseCase : Lets say sitting at home, I want to show my new home to all my friends. I download the mobile app on Android and start live stream on click of the button. My friends, who have also downloaded the same mobile app, can see my live-stream through their mobile. They can also see some of the VOD Content.
I would like to understand how to play the Live Stream / VOD on native Android App ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: The JW Player is not really intended for a native Android App. It is really only for mobile web, currently.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer thanks for your reply,Could you please tell me  what should I use for native android app?

Comment: That I do not know, since I do not really do Android app development.

Comment: We have an official SDK Now - http://www.jwplayer.com/android-sdk/

Comment: No problem! Any time

Answer (score 0):

[OpenMAX](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/openmaxal/) for Android will give you the best flexibility & control, however, it's a low level API that mandate C++ & NDK usage, you can also use [ffmpeg](https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android) static libs in the same manner